# How to do architecture of application?

Tags: java, python, architecture, backend

I have android applicatio on Kotlin which use REST API on Spring. But now i'd like to add Python AI for predict some information. How i can connect Python's AI application with Java's Backend Spring?

Right for example, i have some data in post request in java, must to handle this with Python's AI and return the result. How to do this?

Comment: If they are on the same device, you can use Java.Runtime.Exec (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) for more information. You could also host the Python's AI in a server and make another request to that server. Without more information, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: just i don't know is it best practice to do request from server to another server

Comment: You can do the request to the first server, fetch the results and then from the app make another request to the second server. That way you don't do request from the server to another server directly, but rather from your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [microservices archtecture](https://microservices.io/). So your project would have two backend detached applications running, one with the java code and another with python code.

So your java service would call the python service via http (or another protocol chosen) sending the information needed for Python AI to process. When done, python service would return the response.

If using http, give a try on rest apis for standardize data flow between services.